# Create a slice of buffered channel in golang

Tags: go, channel, buffered

I couldn't find a way to create a slice of buffered channels in golang. I know how to create slice of unbuffered channel given as below

```
type ch chan int
channels := make([]ch,5)
```

Comment: A slice's type does not determine if it is buffered or not; that is determined when you `make` the channel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This statement `channels := make([]ch,5)` is simply allocating the container (the slice of channels which has a length of 5). In addition to that you have to initialize each channel individually which is when you would declare them as buffered rather than unbuffered. So extending your example just do this:

```
for i, _ := range channels {
     channels[i] = make(chan int, BufferSize)
}
```